# Trouble getting ads to display on android with adMob

Tags: android, admob

I've included the relevant portion in my manifest:

```
<meta-data android:value="123456789" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />

            <!-- Track Market installs from AdMob ads -->             
            <receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver" android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                    </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />'
```

and

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>'
```

attrs copied right from the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
            <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
                    <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
                    <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
                    <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
                    <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
                    <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
            </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

My layout (Which is a tabs view btw) is a table with it on its own row:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.icukansas.lenscalculator"
```

and

```
<TableRow>
     <!-- Place an AdMob ad at the bottom of the screen. -->
    <!-- It has white text on a black background. -->
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
      android:layout_span="4"
      android:id="@+id/ad" 
      app:backgroundColor="#000000"
      app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
      app:keywords="security"
    />
    </TableRow>
```

I then call:

```
public class myClass extends Activity implements AdListener{
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_thistab);

    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ad.setAdListener(this);
```

Every time I get onFailedToReceiveAd error in the log.

I'm sure its something easy I'm missing :)

Comment: This question is using attrs.xml, which likely means it's using Admob 4.0.4 or older. 4.1.0 has some changes described in [this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) (look for Tim's post).

Answer (score 1):

Yes You are missing two thing:

1.Most Important :

```
<meta-data android:value="a14e20856e4ad8f" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
```

2.Refresh Interval:

```
 <com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
           myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
           myapp:refreshInterval="30"           
  />
```

Rest looks fine.

Comment: I've got the first one in the AndroidManifest. I just made up the numbers but I have my real ID in my app.

I've added refresh interval to my xml files and still no luck :(

Comment: I ended up putting the ad in my main.xml instead of the tab's xml and its working now.Never could quite figure out why it wouldn't request in my sub activity.

Comment: Hey thanks for the publisher ID now I can publish using yours!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I figured it would be helpful for people trying to put an ad in a tablelayout. I eventually got this to work by including android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" in my TableLayout.  If your span was something other than 4 you would put the same amount of columns/numbers in stretchColumns as your span.

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the netstate permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - friggin tabview. Placing it in the main activity instead of the tabs worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

hi jason
I have solution, may be it will help
write this code in your class

```
AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, // Android emulator
                "5669B77A6042345BC23219DCAC6C15CA",// device id
                });
ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
ad.requestFreshAd();
ad.setAdListener(this);
```

you can get device id in logcat after running application in info tab, search for text.

To get test ads on the emulator use AdManager.setTestDevices...
also set listeners

and you will get your device id, paste it , otherwise your previous code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it problem for almost 3 hours already. I follow all google example. Finaly, i figure it out. You can customized the request, then it will work. In my example, I do this in the Activity class:

```
    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    //re.setTesting(true);
    re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE); 
    adview.loadAd(re);
```

You can check my example here, I always put my apk, and source code. You can download and try:

[Add Google Admob in Android Application](http://android.jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html)